# Text within element moves down when anchor tag applied to it

Tags: css

I have a weird problem that I never encountered before: when I add an anchor tag to text in a `<h1>` or `<li>` element, the text moves down (within this element) a couple of pixels.

Upon adding the anchor, the padding and margin of the containing element do **not** change.

The anchor itself has zero padding and zero margin.

Actually, in the Google Chrome Console, I don't see any style difference between `<li>` elements which do or do not contain 'anchored' text. Nevertheless, the text moves down a bit after applying the anchor to it.

As extra checks, I viewed the page in both Firefox and Google Chome (with and without JavaScript disabled, just in case) but the behavior is persistent.

What am I missing here?

UPDATE: I created a LIVE version of the framework [here](http://www.spss-tricks.com) in order to demonstrate the problem more clearly.

Comment: can you give an example. i can't recreate this.

Comment: @btevfik: yes, please see the update on my OP for a LIVE demo.

Comment: @RubenGeert I am unable to replicate this issue. What browser are you using? I checked it with Chrome 26. It looks fine.

Comment: I can confirm your issue is there in latest Opera (12.15). It's not an answer, by why don't you make the header a permanent link? Almost every website does that...

Comment: @Neograph734: I think it's a bit odd to link to the exact same page that the visitor is already on. But more importantly, this wouldn't solve anything for the `<li>` elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with the `vertical-alignment:middle` that the links get from your “reset” formattings – switch that off in Firebug (line #9 in your `style.css`), and you will notice the text sitting on the same line for the links and the text in your menu list.

Either override the `vertical-alignment` property for your `a` elements in the menu with `top`, or set those links to `display:block`.

Comment: thanks a million, problem solved!! I thought that the `vertical-align` would basically hold for anything on the page. However, it now seems  plain text within a `<li>` has a different `vertical-align` than an `<a>` element. Is that correct?